# Currency 'USD' not found for Gujarati language

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, currency, magento-1.8

I am getting error **Currency 'USD' not found** when i change the language to Gujarati. Every thing is working fine on other languages like English, Spanish, France etc.

I have tried to remove all session and cahce from var/ directory. I am using Magento version 1.8 please help me on this.

Comment: Did you try to remove cache, index management and clear all you sessions after creating GUJARATI store? You can clear sessions from var/sessions folder

Comment: Yes i have removed cache and all session from var folder but doesn't work.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13228/magento-error-currency-usd-not-found/ this could be help to you.

Answer (score 0):

edit file located in `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/gu.xml`

```
<currencies>
        <currency type="INR">
            <symbol>રુ</symbol>
        </currency>
    </currencies>
```

change to

```
<currencies>

   <currency type="INR">
    <symbol>રુ</symbol>
   </currency>

   <currency type="USD">
    <displayName>US Dollar</displayName>
    <symbol>$</symbol>
    </currency>

</currencies>
```